# Date of birth from data attribute

Tags: jquery, date

I want to get values from data-min-date-adt and data-max-date-adt and put them in 3 select fields for date of birth so that user can only pick dates within that range. I tried to get data value, but I don't know how to put that values in 3 select fields, "separate" them and then validate them with jquery validate plug in. 
Please help.

```
<div class="full-date" data-min-date-adt="18.03.2017" data-max-date-adt="18.03.2005"></div>

<div class="field-container">
  <select name="dobDay" class="dobDay">
    <option value="">Day</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="field-container month">
  <select name="dobMonth" class="dobMonth">
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="field-container">
  <select name="dobYear" class="dobYear">
  </select>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hf3wksde/6/)

Comment: Anyone? Is there any solution or suggestion for this?